# Does a positive semidefinite matrix always have a non-negative trace?

Tags: matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite

> If $A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix ($A\succeq 0)$, does it imply that $\mbox{Tr}(A)\geq 0$, where the $\mbox{Tr}(\cdot)$ denotes the trace.

If not, any counter-example? Thanks.

Comment: Suppose a matrix has a negative diagonal element. Can you see that the matrix cannot be positive semidefinite?

Comment: I know most likely this statement is wrong, but I just could not figure out an counter-example.

Comment: @MIMIGA the statement is correct: if $A \succeq 0$, then $\mathrm{Tr}(A) \geq 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Is the converse true? This is, if $\mbox{Tr}(A)\geq 0$, then $A\succeq 0$.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca No.  Consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&-1}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But $A=\left(\begin{array}{l}2&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right)$ is not positive semidefinite matrix. Note that for $x=\left(\begin{array}{l}0 \\ 1\end{array}\right)$ we have $x^{T}Ax\leq 0$.

Comment: @Diego exactly, so this shows that the converse isn't true.

Comment: Even if all diagonal elements are $\ge0$, we need not have $A\succeq0$. Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$. As $\det A=-3$, $A$ has a negative eigenvalue $s$; hence $x^* Ax=x^*sx=s|x|^2<0$ for a corresponding eigenvector $x$.

(This also shows that $A\succeq0$ implies $\sigma(A)\subset[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 38):

Suppose that $A = [a_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^n$ is such that $a_{ii} < 0$ for some $i$.  Let $e_i$ be the $i$th standard basis vector; that is,
$$
e_i = (\overbrace{0,\cdots,0}^{i-1},1,0,\dots,0)
$$
then $e_i^T Ae_i = a_{ii} < 0$, which means that $A$ is not positive semidefinite.

So, if $A$ is positive semidefinite, then all diagonal elements are non-negative, which means that the trace is non-negative.

Answer (score 20):

Yes. If the matrix is semi-positive definite, all the eigenvalues are non-negative. The trace being equal to the sum of eigenvalues, we conclude that the trace has to be non-negative.

Answer (score 7):

We know that positive semi-definite matrices have nonnegative eigenvalues, and the trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues. Because sum of nonnegative numbers is nonnegative, the trace of a positive semi-definite matrix is nonnegative.